quotient topology of $f(x)=|x|$

Let $X$ be $\Bbb R$ with standard topology $\mathcal{T}$, $Y=[0,+\infty)$, $f: X\to Y, x\mapsto |x|$. Is the quotient topology of $Y$ the relative one? that is, the quotient topology of $Y$ is $\mathcal{T}\cap Y$?

By quotient topology, $O$ is open in $Y$ iff $f^{-1}(O)\in \mathcal{T}$, which is equivalent to $O\cup (-O)$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$. Then...hard to calculate furthemore.

Generally

If $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous open surjection between topological spaces, then the quotient topology on $Y$ (induced by $f$) coincides with the original topology on $Y$.
(We say that the function $f : X \to Y$ is open if for every open $U \subseteq X$ the set $f[U] \subseteq Y$ is open.)

Using this fact it suffices to prove that $|x|$ is an open map between $\mathbb{R}$ with the euclidean topology and $[0, \infty)$ with the relative topology. The image of any open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is actually $(U \cup -U) \cap [0, \infty)$, so it is open in $[0, \infty)$ by definition.
It follows that the quotient topology on $[0, \infty)$ does coincide with the relative topology.

It suffices to show that $\{[0, b) : b > 0\} \cup \{(a, b) : 0 < a < b\}$ forms a basis for both topologies.


 Any open set in the relative topology is of the form $O \cap Y$ where $O$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$. Let $y \in O \cap Y$.


   If $y = 0$, then there is some $b > 0$ such that $y \in (-b, b) \subseteq O$. Then $y \in [0, b) \subseteq O \cap Y$.


   If $y > 0$, then there is some $0 < a < b$ such that $y \in (a, b) \subseteq O$. Then $y \in (a, b) \in O \cap Y$.



 If $O$ is open in the quotient topology, then $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$. Let $y \in O$.


 If $y = 0$, then $0 \in f^{-1}(O)$, so there is some $b > 0$ such that $(-b, b) \subseteq f^{-1}(O)$. Then $y \in [0, b) \subseteq O$.


 If $y > 0$, then $y \in f^{-1}(O)$, so there is some $0 < a < b$ such that $y \in (a, b) \subseteq f^{-1}(O)$. Then $y \in (a,b) \subseteq O$ as well.


Is this just prove that the quotient topology is coarser than the relative one?

Technically one should prove that the family is contained in both topologies to begin with. It is simple enough to be left as an exercise, but formally until this is done we have not proved any of the inclusions, and once this is done we have proved both. (Not saying that the answer lacks anything, just clarifying how the logic works here. )
